# Creating a Contact with a Customer External Id

Tags: netsuite

Is it possible to create a contact through the NetSuite SOAP API (SuiteTalk) for a customer using the customer external id? I tried setting the RecordRef external id and type to customer but received the error "Nonexistent externalId 123 for company" but a customer with that external id does exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned that you already checked that externalid exists for the customer. This error is seen when the customer record is inactive. Can you check if the customer is active or not. If it's not then try integrating with an active customer. Please let me know if this works! Thanks